# I want to understand why this works the way it does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I've been working with React for a while now buh I always have this problem when I'm trying to update a state in either **redux** or react **useState**.

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState(null);
const handleFileUpload = e => {
  setFiles(e.target.files[0]);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(files);
  }, 5000);
}
```

I ran the code without setTimeout initially but apparently the logged value is null in the first instance but the state gets updated after console.log runs so I use setTimeout as a fallback to test the bit of code as setTimeout is asynchronous and hence non blocking but still the state is only updated after setTimeout runs why please? What am I doing wrong?

Note: I only assume the state is been updated because I set the value of the input file to be **file.name** so as to make state the single source of truth

Comment: It's React internal when the state value will be changed. As this is asynchronous. when SetState fires a rerender of teh component happens , as your timeout is still in the current render cycle, it will execute first then the component will get rerenderd.

Comment: The short answer is that state setting is asynchronous in React. If you want to adjust to state changes using hooks then use the useEffect hook

Comment: @charlietfl I suspected that useState is asynchronous because it has caused a lot of bugs in my codes where an asynchronous code depends on the state change to run but I have not been able to find references to read on the inner workings of useState as such have just been using a rather verbose workaround

Comment: You would use both

Comment: @charlietfl Yh you're right I'll just use useEffect to listen for state changes adding the state in my dependency array

Comment: @Asutosh Please fix your edit. Not sure why you put this in a stack snippet since it requires dependencies to run it